# Displaying Web Server's Responses

Tags: python, html, fastapi

I have a simple html web page that contains two textfield and one button. When the button is clicked, it will send a get request to the web server containing the first name and last name as parameters. "GET /fname=Mary&lname=Jane" to the web server. The web server will then return a response "Hello, Mary Jane".

How do I go about processing and displaying the return response on the html web page just underneath the button? Also how do I go about returning both a text response ("Hello, Mary Jane") as well as the html page at the same time so that the textfields and the query parameters can be cleared and get ready for the next submit.

[this is how the url look like after submission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHYqM.jpg)

I am currently using python and fastapi for the web server.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form>
  <label for="fname">First name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

> 

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates  
  
app = FastAPI()
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")
    
    
@app.get('/')
def root(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request})
```

Comment: How do you make the request?

Comment: Look into ajax/javascript, editing html elements and fastapi, then write a specific question about something not working/being weird.

Comment: @LukasSchmid the submit button will send a get request with the query parameters back to the web server seen in the screenshot in this thread.